# Javascript - A unknown JSON object was returned to me, how do I look at it?

Tags: javascript, json, facebook-graph-api

I'm having this situation. In my FB.api call, a unknown JSON object was returned to me. I'm trying to figure out how to look into this JSON object!

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', wallPost , function(response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
              alert('Error occured' + response);
            } else {
              alert('Post ID: ' + response);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "look into the JSON"? You want to see the structure of JSON ?

Comment: what is your **wallPost** object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download firebug for firefox and put a  breakpoint in that function and then hover over that variable and firebug should show you all of its properties and objects. Or use Chromes console to do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Try console.log(response) instead of alert. Then check the firebug console.

Answer (score 0):

If you have firebug installed, do:

```
console.log(response);
```

Then you can debug the structure of the JSON object using Firebug from the console-tab.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a `console.log` of the data. You can also iterate over its keys to look at each entry individually, or if you know *some* of them, just pick out those.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to remove that console.log command after you tested your code. Browser with no support for this will complain.